# Netbeans project fails to generate jar file in dist folder

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have a Netbeans Javafx project under development that has been working fine. After stopping work on the project for a few months, i get back to it, run a build, but the "dist" folder is empty. Even after a clean build, the dist folder turns up empty with no jars.

The build output log shows this:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\MEMMCOL      
Documents\\Codes\\Netbeans\\MMXExplorerPlus" jfx-rebuild
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\classes\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\classes\META-INF
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 49 source files to C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\classes
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 27 files to C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\dist
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\project.properties
jar:
jfx-rebuild:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Then when i click the run button, i see this:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\MEMMCOL Documents\\Codes\\Netbeans\\MMXExplorerPlus" jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Updating property file: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\project.properties
jar:
Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\dist\run1394106374
jfx-project-run:
Executing C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\dist\run1394106374\MMXExplorerPlus.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre/bin/java
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\dist\run1394106374\MMXExplorerPlus.jar
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\HP\Documents\MEMMCOL Documents\Codes\Netbeans\MMXExplorerPlus\dist\run1394106374
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.

I'm using 
Netbeans 8.0.2, and Jdk 1.8

Comment: Check "Project Properties -> Packaging -> Build JAR after compiling"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes that option is checked, still no jar file in dist folder